# What do the symbols $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ mean on this discrete math problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

Currently I have come across a problem set which I cannot decipher or begin to ask or search because I do not know what kind of notation or problems these are.

> Please circle the best description:
>
> a. If $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_7$ by $f(n)=[n]$, then $f$ is one to one. `True` `False`
>
> b. $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ has no zero divisors. `True` `False`
>
> c. In $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$, $[3]$ is a zero divisor. `True` `False`
>
> d. In $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, $[3][4]=[1]$ (multiplication). `True` `False`

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Attw0.jpg))

My thoughts:

a. $\mathbb{Z}$ implies $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

b. $\mathbb{Z}$ represents $12$ but $3$ and $4$ are zero divisors. **False**

c. $\mathbb{Z}$ represents $15$ in which divided by $3 = 0$. Thus **True**

d. I have no idea

Comment: Specifically which things are giving you trouble?  Do you know what $\Bbb Z$ is?  Or a one-to-one function?  Or $\Bbb Z_{12}$?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ stands for Zahlen.

Comment: @alex.jordan I don't think that's very helpful.

Comment: @CameronWilliams It's just a comment. Zev has it covered.

Comment: The arrow $\to$ can mean implication (which is what you seem to be latching on to) or it could be used to denote the destination of a function. Functions can be thought of maps from one set to another and the way we think about it is as follows. Suppose $f$ takes values in the set $X$ and gives us values in the set $Y$, then we would write $f:X\to Y$ - read: $f$ maps $X$ to $Y$. So in (a), $f$ is taking values in $\Bbb Z$ and giving values in $\Bbb Z_7$.

Comment: Would someone also point me to a formatting guide to get these awesome characters.

Comment: You can search the web for $\LaTeX$ help.  I would claim the single arrow is ambiguous between the domain and range of a function and implies.  $\LaTeX$ renders  \implies as a double arrow $\implies$ .  I am certainly not a good source for the proper formatting of arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}$ refers to the set of integers (*[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)*),
$$\large \mathbb{Z}=\{\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots\}$$
$\mathbb{Z}_n$ for some number $n$, in this context, refers to the "integers modulo $n$" (*[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)*, notation is *[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n)* but I recommend reading the full article), the set
$$\large\mathbb{Z}_n=\{[0],[1],\ldots[n-1]\}\\[0.1in]
{\small\text{also sometimes written as}}\;\;\large\{\overline{0},\overline{1},\ldots,\overline{n-1}\}$$
On each $\mathbb{Z}_n$, an addition and multiplication operation can be defined. For example,
$$\begin{align*}
\large[2] + [5] &\large = [3] \quad\text{in }\mathbb{Z}_{4} & \quad\large[2] \cdot [3] &\large = [2]\quad\text{in }\mathbb{Z}_{4}\\[0.1in]
\large[2] + [5] &\large = [0] \quad\text{in }\mathbb{Z}_{7} & \quad\large[2] \cdot [3] &\large = [6]\quad\text{in }\mathbb{Z}_{7}
\end{align*}$$
I would assume that, if these notations are showing up in your homework, they've been covered in class or are explained in the textbook - do you understand the examples above?

---

It seems  you're also confused by the notation for functions (*[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29)*, notation is *[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Notation)* but I recommend reading the full article).

Comment: Yes, Thank you. Notation varies widely among many discrete teacher. This clears it up. Just to make sure Zn is not a set of integers say if n is 7...{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.

Comment: @MooCow: That's right, each of the sets $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is totally separate (fancy word: *disjoint*) from each other and from $\mathbb{Z}$, even though you might see the same symbols used for their elements. So even if someone is lazy and says
$$\large 3\in\mathbb{Z}_{7}\quad (\text{read: “3 is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$”})$$
they **mean** the element $[3]$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$, not the **integer** $3$. Moreover, the $[3]$ inside $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$ is different  (despite having the same name) as the one inside $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$, the one inside $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers to b and c are correct, but c is not expressed well and I worry that shows a lack of understanding.  What do you mean by $\Bbb Z$ represents $k$?  For a, the arrow is not implies, it is showing the domain and range of the function $f$.  So you are taking $n \in \Bbb Z$ to $n \pmod 7$.  Is this one to one? For d, your answers to b and c seem to indicate you know $\Bbb Z_{12}$ is the integers $\pmod {12}$, so what is $3 \times 4$ in that ring?

Comment: In the image for d. the right side of the problem looks like [1] [multiplication]

Comment: I do not know if that helps

Comment: Do Zev Chonoles' recent edits answer your question?  You need to understand "integers mod $n$".  That is the point of the exercise.